# Limit of $(\frac{n}{n+1})^n$

Tags: limits

How do i find the Limit of $(\frac{n}{n+1})^n$ as n tends to infinity. I know the limit of $\frac{n}{n+1}$ tends to 1 but what about to the power of n

Answer (score 2):

use that $$\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n=\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. One may recall that
$$
\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{\ln (1+u)}{u}=1
$$ giving
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\ln (1+\frac1n)}{\frac1n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\:\ln\!\left[ \:\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\:\right]=1.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Write in $x=e^{\ln x}$ form, rearrange and use L'Hopital's rule:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \big(\frac{n}{n+1}\big)^n=e^{\lim_{n\to \infty}\ln\big(\frac{n}{n+1}\big)^n}=e^{\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\ln n - \ln(n+1)}{\frac1n} }=e^{\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\frac1n - \frac1{n+1}}{\frac{-1}{n^2}}}=e^{\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{-n^2}{n^2+1}} = e^{-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

You can use PFD to write the limit as $$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n=\lim_{n \to +\infty} \left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^n$$

Then you use the subtitution rule $t=-(n+1)$ and you get that 
$$\lim_{t \to +\infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{t}\right)^{-t-1}=\lim_{t \to +\infty} \exp\left((-t-1)\log\left(1+\frac{1}{t}\right)\right)\underbrace{=}_{l'Hopital's}e^{\lim_{t \to +\infty}\left(\log\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{t}\right)}{-\frac{1}{t+1}}\right)}=e^{\lim_{t \to +\infty}\left(-\frac{t+1}{t}\right)}=e^{\lim_{t \to +\infty}\left(-\frac{\frac{1}{t}+1}{t}\right)}=e^{-1}=\frac{1}{e}$$

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you defined $e$, the answer is quite easy.

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac n{n+1}\right)^n =\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{n+1}n\right)^{-n} =\left(\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac 1 n\right)^n\right)^{-1}=e^{-1} $$

If you defined $e$ by the power series though, the last step is not trivial.

Answer (score 0):

$$(\frac {n}{n+1})^n=(\frac{n+1}{n})^{-n}=((n+\frac{1}{n})^n)^{-1}$$ which tends(by definition of number e) to $$e^{-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Since on puttingLet $$y=\lim_{n\to \infty} \biggl(\frac{n}{n+1}\biggr)^n $$
Taking natural logarithm on both sides, 
$$\ln y =\lim_{n\to \infty} n\biggl(\ln\bigl(\frac{n}{n+1}\bigr)\biggr) $$
$$\ln y =\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\biggl(\ln\bigl(\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}}\bigr)\biggr)}{\frac{1}{n}} $$
Now using L'Hopital rule,
$$\ln y =\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\frac{-1}{1+\frac{1}{n}}\frac{-1}{n^2}}{\frac{-1}{n^2}} $$
$$\ln y =\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{-1}{1+\frac{1}{n}} $$
Now on putting the value of n, we get,
$$\ln y=-1$$
Hence,$$y=e^{-1}$$Which is the answer