# Find limit of the sequence without using limit of the function

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, limits

Given sequence:
$$ x_n=\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n $$
Find limit of the sequence without using rules and theorems for limits of functions (e.g no L'Hopitals Rule).

I believe that in order to find limit of this sequence you have to somehow use well-known limit:
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{n + 1}{n}\right)^n = e $$

Comment: It is just $\frac{1}{e}$.  Note that $1/x_n$ converges to $e$ and use the fact that $x_n$ converges to $x\neq 0$ then $1/x_n$ converges $1/x$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limit of $(\frac{n}{n+1})^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2547287/limit-of-fracnn1n)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply find the [relationship to the $\exp$-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function#Formal_definition) via paraphrase, but you can also simply look for a [serial expansion](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=Series%20representations%201%2Fe) that describes the situation.

###### relationship to the $\exp$-function

By rearranging with the power rules we get:

$$
\begin{align*}
x_{n} &= \left( \frac{n}{n + 1} \right)^{n}\\
x_{n} &= \left( \left( \frac{n + 1}{n} \right)^{-1} \right)^{n}\\
x_{n} &= \left( \frac{n + 1}{n} \right)^{-1 \cdot n}\\
x_{n} &= \left( \left( \frac{n + 1}{n} \right)^{n} \right)^{-1}\\
x_{n} &= \left( \left( \frac{n}{n} + \frac{1}{n} \right)^{n} \right)^{-1}\\
x_{n} &= \left( \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^{n} \right)^{-1}\\
x_{n} &= \frac{1}{\left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^{n}}\\
\\
\lim_{{n} \to {\infty}} x_{n} &= \lim_{{n} \to {\infty}} \frac{1}{\left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^{n}}\\
\lim_{{n} \to {\infty}} x_{n} &= \frac{1}{\lim_{{n} \to {\infty}} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^{n}} \quad\mid\quad e := \lim_{{n} \to {\infty}} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^{n}\\
\lim_{{n} \to {\infty}} x_{n} &= \frac{1}{e} = e^{-1} = 0.3678\dots\\
\end{align*}
$$